# Django 2.0 multiselect issue

Tags: python, django, multi-select, django-crispy-forms

I am testing 2.0 and have encountered the same error in two different places.

It has to do with multi-select.  I get the following error.

```
Exception Value: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)
```

here is the code from crispy-forms-foundation

```
{% if not field|is_checkbox and not field|is_checkboxselectmultiple %}
  {% crispy_field field %}
{% endif %}
```

the other package error was from: localflavor.us.models import USStateField, PhoneNumberField, USZipCodeField

What do I need to change to get these to work properly in 2.0?

Cheers

Comment: has `crispy-forms-foundation` been updated to work with django2.0? The github would suggest not: https://github.com/sveetch/crispy-forms-foundation. In that case you'll need to wait either for someone to update the library or better yet, submit a pull request that fixes it yourself :)

Comment: what can I do to update it - don't want to wait.  Did 2.0 change the way tuples are handled?

Comment: I don't know the specifics, I do know that Django 2.0 updated the admin considerably so I wouldn't be surprised if the way multi-select and other widgets work was changed, and `crispy-forms-foundation` hasn't been updated to reflect that change. As for how you update it, thats possibly another question but you start by raising an issue on that github page, seeing if you get a response, and if not you're left with having to fork the library, rewrite it to work with Django2.0, and then using your forked version in your code

Comment: thank you.  I have informed the packages and the localflavor package will be updated this week.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it to work. Appears to be a Django 2 thing.

My previous code worked perfectly fine with the CharField.  Now you have to use ChoiceField.

I hope this helps.  Cheers.

```
# before 
case = forms.CharField ( label = "", widget = forms.Select ( choices = qs ) )

# now
case = forms.ChoiceField ( label = "", widget = forms.Select, choices = qs  )
```